# Filter and modify list object using java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I'am using spring and I defined bean with `ArrayList`. `invites` it is a list with `Invite` objects.

```
@Getter
public class Invite {

    private String invitee;
    private String email;
    private boolean confirm;
    private String token;
}
```

This is my data privider class :

```
@Getter
public class InvitationsData {

    private List<Invite> invites = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostConstruct
    private void initInvites(){
        invites.add(new Invite("John", "john@john.com", false, "6456453"));
        invites.add(new Invite("John", "john@john.com", false, "3252352"));
    }
}
```

In configuration class I created `@Bean` from `InvitationsData` - it works.

In the service I would like to modify one object from list which matches to token string and have set `confirm` to `false`.

```
invitationsData.getInvites()
               .stream()
               .filter(i -> token.equals(i.getToken()))
               .filter(i -> !i.isConfirm())
               .forEach(i -> {
                   i.setConfirm(true);
               });
```

This stream works fine. Now, when someone call method twice for confirmed object I would like to throw `CustomException`. How can I do this with this stream? Where can I put `orElseThrow`?

EDIT:

My current solution. I use `peek` instead of `forEach`

```
invitationsData
                .getInvites()
                .stream()
                .filter(i -> token.equals(i.getToken()))
                .filter(i -> !i.isConfirm())
                .peek(i -> i.setConfirm(true))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new InvitationConfirmedException("Error"));
```

Comment: Is token unique or multiple Invite can have same ?

Comment: you can put the check inside `forEach`

Comment: @azro token is unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If the `token` is **unique** you can do :

  ```
  getInvites().stream()
              .filter(i -> token.equals(i.getToken()))
              .filter(i -> !i.isConfirm())
              .findAny()
              .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new)
              .setConfirm(true);
  ```
- If not :

  ```
  getInvites().stream()
              .filter(i -> token.equals(i.getToken()))
              .forEach(i -> {
                  if (i.isConfirm()) 
                      throw new CustomException();
                  else 
                      i.setConfirm(true);
              });
  ```

Comment: the code for when the token is not unique, it will skip the other valid ones as soon as the exception is thrown.. unless it is caught right there in foreach

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to azro answer, for anyone who have a similar scenario, in case you're not sure if the object is on the list, and if it is ok for it not to be, you might prefer to not throw the exception if nothing is found. The code will be like:

```
getInvites().stream()
        .filter(i -> token.equals(i.getToken()))
        .filter(i -> !i.isConfirm())
        .findAny()
        .ifPresent(i -> i.setConfirm(true));
```